# Read a sequence of images in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I got a problem with reading a sequence of images in opencv. I use the same code:

```
namedWindow("Source", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
string pathToData("OpenCV Images/checkerboard1.pgm");

VideoCapture sequence(pathToData);

Mat src;
for (;;)
{   
    sequence >> src;
    if(src.empty())
    {
        cout << "End of Sequence" << endl;
        break;
    }
    imshow("Source", src);
    waitKey(1000);
}
waitKey(0);
```

I run this code in window (visual studio) and in linux. In window, the program shows all images in the sequence, while in linux, the progam just shows the first image in the same sequence. 
Furthermore, in window, the program loads images in grayscale while in lunix it loads images in color. Actually, I save the image as grayscale.

Is this a problem with openCV for window and linux OS? Or Do I need to do some setting? Or something else...
Can someone help me figure it out?
Thank!

Comment: afaik, that VideoCapture trick needs a proper *format* string like : `string pathToData("OpenCV Images/checkerboard%d.pgm");`

Answer (score 0):

`pathToData` contains a file name instead of path. This file is in `.pgm` format meaning that the image is of gray scale.

In my opinion, you will have to create a list of the image names present in the folder and call these names one by one later. The current code will only show `checkerboard1.pgm` image. Or you must give a video file as input instead of the image.